# Can I use AltGr + ' to produce ` (grave accent) in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, qwerty

Can I use AltGr + ' to produce ` (grave accent) in Windows?

This is the default behaviour in Linux, I'd like to do the same on Windows.

I'm using Windows 10 with a QWERTY italian keyboard which, obviously, doesn't have a grave accent button.

Comment: You can do anything you like with AutoHotKey. But doesn't the grave accent combine with other letters?

Comment: In Windows, ` is outputted by typing `96` on the keypad while pressing the ALT key. I agree that on Linux it's much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) with the following script :

```
LControl & RAlt::Send, ``
```

Comment: Left control? mm AltGr and ' ..... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#/media/File:Italian_Keyboard_layout.svg